# Chapter title and abstract in the same page

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, chapters, abstract

I'm writing a report and I need to write an abstract for the chapter after the chapter title in the same page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't just use the regular `abstract` environment provided by the [`report` document class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls), since it puts it on a page of its own. However, a slight modification to that environment (or creating a similar one without the conditional page breaking) - provided below as `chapabstract` - works without problem:

[image: New chapter abstract]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{chapabstract}{%
    \begin{center}%
      \bfseries Chapter Abstract
    \end{center}}%
   {\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{chapabstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{chapabstract}
\section{A section}

%=====

\chapter{Second chapter}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
\lipsum[1]
\end{adjustwidth}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

[`changepage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) also provides the `adjustwidth` environment (where you specify the left/right indent), which allows for setting of contents in a narrower context. These two could be combined, if needed.

Comment: thanks, I'm surprised that worked perfectly, I was using the abstract environment at the first place, and I thought whatever you put after the \chapter (in a report class) will be in the next page, just like the abstract environment used to do ...

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me, thanks, however, a note for those using \include for each chapter, make sure your \chapter is inside your included file since include will add a page break.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather use a list to define such environments to get the margins adjusted in one
step and to be able to adjust indentation and paragraph separation.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{summary}
               {\begin{center}\textbf{Abstract}\end{center}
                 \list{}{\listparindent 1em%
                        %\setlength{\leftmargin}{<value>} adjust if you need
                        \itemindent\listparindent
                        \rightmargin\leftmargin
                        \parsep\z@ \@plus\p@}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{summary}
\lipsum[3]
\end{summary}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I have allowed for a heading (but it looks ugly, so if you do not need it remove the 
`\begin{center}...\end{center}.` The left and right margin is the same as those found in the
quotation environment to keep the style constant. If you need to change it use:

```
\setlength{\leftmargin}{<value>}
```

within the definition.

Comment: thanks for that brillant suggestion, it works as well ..

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, or I would just put this as a comment, but I found all I had to do was include the `notitlepage` option in the documentclass line. The following produces the exact same output as Werner's answer.

```
 \documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \begin{document}
 \chapter{First chapter}
 \begin{abstract}
 \lipsum[1]
 \end{abstract}
 \section{A section}

 %=====

 \chapter{Second chapter}
 \begin{abstract}
 \lipsum[1]
 \end{abstract}
 \section{A section}
 \lipsum
 \end{document}
```

Also remember that using `\include{somefile}` will put a page break before the contents of the file. I had this error because my abstracts were in separate files. Moving things around or using `\input{somefile}` instead fixed it for me.